# how to add equation and R squared value when creating scatter graphs with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, trendline

I'm trying to create a scatter graph using Highcharts. There's a sample that shows how to add a trend line. However, I don't see anywhere where we could add the equation and the r-squared value like what we normally do in Excel.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194770/highcharts-area-range-plot-in-rcharts) is what you are looking for. Is it also related to javascript(you added the tag)?

Comment: yes. highcharts is an interactive javascript chart...

Comment: You need to calculate values - by default Highcharts won't calculate this for you. I think you need [Highcharts-Regression](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression) plugin.

Comment: Hi Pawel. I took a look at the plugin you gave me. Equation is readily available. The R squared value is also available via the cofiguration. Thanks a lot for the help! It works like a charm! :D

Answer (score -1):

In order to show the r squared value:

https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression/issues/38

As per phpepe:

> Add "%r2"  to the legend and will replaced with the calculated value.
>   You can add the equation as well as shown in the examples.